# How can I get the broker that a topic belongs to in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a cluster of kafka brokers. I am trying to get metrics at the topic level, which I have done successfully for topics residing on the specific broker that the  code points to. Zookeeper returns a list of all topics on all brokers. This results in failures when I try and get metrics across every topic.

I am using this function to get a list of topics from zookeeper:

```
ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper("kafka.ip:port", 1000, null);
return zk.getChildren("/brokers/topics", false);
```

To get the topic metrics I am using JMX. The JMX Connector only points to a single broker. When the code I use to get metrics hits a topic that does not live on that broker, it fails because the topic does not exist in the eyes of the broker.

This leads to my question: Is there a way I can get the broker that a topic lives on? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the brokers where the partitions of the topic leave you can use AdminClient interface. Something like

```
AdminClient kafkaClient = new AdminClient(properties)) 
DescribeTopicsResult result = kafkaClient.describeTopics(Collections.singleton(topicName));
Map<String, TopicDescription> descriptions = result.all().get();
descriptions.values().stream().forEach(t->{
    t.partitions().stream().forEach(p->{
        Node leader = p.leader(); //here is a leader for partition
        List<Node> replicas = p.replicas(); //here are the replicas
     });
 });
```

Though I am not sure this is a good idea in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Kafka topic is divided into a number of partitions. These partitions are distributed across multiple brokers. Considering this it's not quite clear what would you like to get.

Comment: I would like to get the address or name of  the broker that the lead topic replication lives on.

Comment: @AustinBrinegar, there is no such thing as a lead topic; each Kafka broker contains a number of partitions and each of these partitions can be either a leader or a replica.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I'm looking to get the address or name of the broker that the lead partition lives on.